# How can I find a value of $n$ which yields the minimal difference between $\frac{2^n}{88}$ and $\Big[\frac{2^n}{88}\Big]$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $[x]$ denote the rounded (nearest integer) value of $x$.

How can I find a value of $n$ which yields the minimal difference between $\dfrac{2^n}{88}$ and $\Big[\dfrac{2^n}{88}\Big]$?

Empirically, I have noticed that the minimal value of $\dfrac{1}{11}$ can be achieved with any $n=5k+3$:

- $\Big|\dfrac{2^{ 3}}{88}-\Big[\dfrac{2^{ 3}}{88}\Big]\Big|=\dfrac{1}{11}$
- $\Big|\dfrac{2^{ 8}}{88}-\Big[\dfrac{2^{ 8}}{88}\Big]\Big|=\dfrac{1}{11}$
- $\Big|\dfrac{2^{13}}{88}-\Big[\dfrac{2^{13}}{88}\Big]\Big|=\dfrac{1}{11}$
- $\Big|\dfrac{2^{18}}{88}-\Big[\dfrac{2^{18}}{88}\Big]\Big|=\dfrac{1}{11}$
- $\dots$

---

My questions:

- If this is wrong, then what is the correct value of $n$?
- If this is correct, then how can it be proved mathematically?
- What is the general method for any natural divisor other than $88$?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As $(2^n,88)=8$  for $n\ge3$

Check for $n=0,1,2$

let use start with $2^{n-3}\pmod{11}$

Now $2^5\equiv10\pmod{11},2^{10}\equiv10^2\equiv1$

So, the difference should be minimum for $n\equiv3\pmod{10}$ if $n\ge3$

Comment: Thanks. My browser shows "[Math Processing Error]" in red. I will refer to your answer as soon as it shows clearly.

Comment: How does this prove it is the minimum?

Comment: @cr001, $$2^n\pmod{88}$$ will be minimum iff $$2^{n-3}\pmod{11}$$ is minimum assuming $n\ge3$. We need to test $n=0,1,2$ separately

Comment: Can you please explain the notation $(2^n,88)=8$?

Comment: @barakmanos, $(a,b)$ means gcd$(a,b)$

Comment: Okay got it, thanks.

Comment: Got it. So the general method is to find the greatest value of $n$ such that the denominator ($88$ in this case) is divisible by $2^n$?

Comment: $n=0$ gives $\frac{1}{88}$.. (Just saying)